# .svc web service broken when moving to IIS 7

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows, web-services

I'm trying to move an application from IIS 6 to IIS 7.  I've managed to get everything working except for the web services (.svc files).  These return `404` exceptions.

In the failed request logs I get the following warning, and everything else appears fine:

```
131.

MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS
Warning

ModuleName="IsapiModule", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", HttpStatus="404", HttpReason="Not Found", HttpSubStatus="0", ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully.
 (0x0)", ConfigExceptionInfo="" 
10:32:51.134
```

when I do a GET request for service.svc it works fine, and returns the page that begins:

```
You have created a service.

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:
```

but when a request is made to the service, via a POST request, it results in the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're server and the application in general is set to allow the POST verb?  It sounds a lot like the server, your application or a combination of the two is either not explicitly set to allow POSTs.

Make sure your web.config file contains all of the relevant configuration settings needed to get an ASP.NET application running on IIS 7 or 7.5